# Problema de java na integração do Mathcad e ModeFrontier

Tags: java, otimização

Eu estou testando o modeFrontier com um simples problema de otimização multi-objectivo
de [ESTECO A simple multi-objective optimization problem](http://www.math.unipd.it/~marcuzzi/DIDATTICA/LEZ&ESE_PIAI_Matematica/3_cones.pdf)

O ModeFrontier consegue gerar as variáveis de entrada `h` e `r` porém não consegue gerar as variáveis de saída `b`, `l` e `v`

[image: Designs Table]

Eu fiz o teste de configuração do mathcad. Daí obtive a seguinte mensagem:

> java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread;
>   nested exception is: 
>       java.rmi.RemoteException: Exception starting the process; nested exception is: 
>       java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
>       java.rmi.RemoteException: Initialization error; nested exception is: 
>       com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object

[image: Mathcad test]

Preferências do Mathcad no ModeFrontier:
[image: Mathcad Preferences in modeFrontier]

Configuração do Mathcad. Script Security:
[image: Mathcad Preferences Script Security]

O diagrama do exemplo no ModeFrontier:

[image: ModeFrontier diagram]

O arquivo do Mathcad:

[image: Mathcad worksheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não sei a razão desse problema, mas eu consegui resolver rodando o modeFRONTIER como Administrador.

Há muitos problemas se o modeFRONTIER não for executado como administrador.
Então, eu recomendo rodar sempre como administrador.

Para rodar sempre como administrador, você pode ir para o ícone do modeFRONTIER. Clicar com o Botão direito do mouse nele e clique em Propriedades. Finalmente, clique no botão de verificação "Executar como administrador".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]